# Terraform as Docker returns error on plan

Tags: docker, terraform

I am trying Terraform as Docker. I have pulled the image from:

[Docker Repo Image](https://hub.docker.com/r/hashicorp/terraform/)

I have simple *main.tf*:

> output "greetings" {
>     value       = "Hello World!"
>   }
>
> provider "random" {}

Now, in the same dir as *main.tf* I run:

> docker run -i -t hashicorp/terraform:light plan main.tf

as it is suggested on that page. But I get the error:

> stat main.tf: no such file or directory

So I guess that I need to create a Dockerfile to create an image including the *main.tf*, right?

thanks.

Comment: Terraform is distributed as a single static binary.  You don't need Docker to run it at all.

Comment: thanks, indeed I know that. But I wanted to try the Docker version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you need to make sure that your terraform files are available inside the container. This can be done using volumes as it is shown below

```
$>  docker run -it -v $PWD:/tr-scripts  hashicorp/terraform:light plan /tr-scripts/
```

second, you may need to run `init` before the `plan`

dockerfile example

```
From hashicorp/terraform:light
COPY ./TR-SCRIPT /tr-scripts

RUN terraform init /tr-scripts
```

Comment: thanks this helps (beside you need to add a "/" after $PWD). That said, I run first "init" and is ok. Afterwards I run plan but i get error: Error: Could not satisfy plugin requirements


Plugin reinitialization required. Please run "terraform init".

Comment: Do I need to run init and plan in the same docker command? Or use a Dockerfile?

Comment: running the init in the same command will not work, you need to create a custom docker file for this